# Get src of child in js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare 2 elements , when they are text this works:

```
if (first.children().text() != second.children().text())
```

But when they are are images neither one of two below works, any ideas?

```
if (first.children().getAttribute('src') != second.children().getAttribute('src'))
if (first.children().src() != second.children().src())
```

Comment: [`.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) is a method of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/) and `.src()` doesn't exist. -> [Attributes | jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/attributes/) / https://api.jquery.com

Comment: Note that calling `attr()` or `text()` on a collection of elements will only ever look at the first one. If you need to consider *all* child elements you'll need a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getAttribute()` is not a jQuery function, it's a native JS function that can be [called on a DOM element](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp).

You're looking for jQuery's [`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.